# How can i export Multiple With Routers

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to export both of these exponents withrouter so i can use props.location.

```
            ./src/App.js
            Attempted import error: 'MobileMenu' is not exported from 
           './components/Navbar'.

          module.exports = {
            Navbar: withRouter(Navbar),
            MobileMenu: withRouter(MobileMenu)
          };

      import { MobileMenu, Navbar } from './components/Navbar';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let Navbar =   withRouter(Navbar)
export { Navbar };

let MobileMenu = withRouter(MobileMenu)
export { MobileMenu };
```